# Optimizing distance distHaversine model for large df in R

Tags: r, optimization, haversine

I'm working with a large dataset and I'm trying to run geospatial analysis on a local machine with 8GB of RAM. It looks like I have exceeded the resources of my machine and I'm wondering whether I can optimize my model so I can run it on my machine.

```
area <- data.frame(area = c('Baker Street','Bank'),
                  lat = c(51.522236,51.5134047),
                  lng = c(-0.157080, -0.08905843),
                  radius = c(100,2000)
)

stop <- data.frame(station = c('Angel','Barbican','Barons Court','Bayswater'),
                   lat = c(51.53253,51.520865,51.490281,51.51224),
                   lng = c(-0.10579,-0.097758,-0.214340,-0.187569),
                   postcode = c('EC1V','EC1A', 'W14', 'W2'))



library(geosphere)


datNew = lapply(1:nrow(area), function(i) {

  df = stop

  df$dist = distHaversine(df[,c("lng", "lat")], 
                          area[rep(i,nrow(df)), c('lng','lat')])

  df$in_circle = ifelse(df$dist <= area[i, "radius"], "Yes", "No")

  df$circle_id = area[i, "area"]

  df

})

datNew = do.call(rbind, datNew)

require(dplyr)    
datNew  <- datNew %>% 
  group_by(station) %>% 
  slice(which.min(dist))
```

Is it possible to calculate the distance and then find the minimum distance in `station` by `station` so that I don't end up with multiplying the the number of `stations` by number of `area`? Or is there another solution that would allow me to run this in a less resource consuming way or split the jobs so it fits into RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting gc() at the end off the lapply function? It frees the memory space for the next iteration. If this does not help ill try to come back to this answer tommorow, just please reply :)

EDIT:

I dont know if you had this in mind but here you go:

```
library(geosphere)
library("plyr")
library("magrittr")

area <- data.frame(area = c('Baker Street','Bank'),
                   lat = c(51.522236,51.5134047),
                   lng = c(-0.157080, -0.08905843),
                   radius = c(100,2000)
)

stop <- data.frame(station = c('Angel','Barbican','Barons Court','Bayswater'),
                   lat = c(51.53253,51.520865,51.490281,51.51224),
                   lng = c(-0.10579,-0.097758,-0.214340,-0.187569),
                   postcode = c('EC1V','EC1A', 'W14', 'W2'))

## In the function below you take an area one by one and then save the station which at the minimal
## distance from the given area

min.dist <- ddply(area, ~area, function(xframe){

  xframe <<- xframe
  cat("Calculating minimum distance from area...", as.character(xframe$area), "\n")

  dists <- distHaversine(xframe[, c("lat", "lng")], stop[ , c("lat", "lng")]) 
  stop.min <- stop[which(min(dists)==dists), ]
  stop.min$area <- xframe$area
  return(stop.min)
  gc()

})

min.dist # the new data frame
```

Comment: The problem that I have is that the `df` that the function creates is too big to then do the grouping, so I was would like to do something where I calculate the distance to each point and find the minimum distance point by point so I don't create the large `df` that I can't process afterwards if that makes sense. Or maybe there is an even better solution that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your help!